# Short story about a future where everyone is equal

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, dystopia

I remember reading a short story about someone who travels to the/a future where everyone is equal.

It was discovered that equality could only be achieved if everyone looked identical (they found people with blue eyes considered themselves superior to people with brown eyes), everyone wore the same clothes (some kind of grey) and males were indistinguishable to females.  There was also something about humans being selected for reproduction.

I am drawing a complete blank as to who it was, or what it was called, and Google isn't helping.

Any ideas?

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate of those answers for "This Perfect Day".  Links follow:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66769/searching-for-giver-like-novel/66808#66808

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/65480/trying-to-recall-a-book-cover-art-heterochromia-plot-with-genetic-mutations-a/65482#65482

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/145925/book-with-boy-with-one-different-colored-eye/145928#145928

Comment: In particular the part about the eye color making a difference. "Chip, is a typical child Member who, through a mistake in genetic programming, has one green eye."

Comment: The difference in this is that it is not a time travel story. Are you sure about that component?

Comment: This seems similar to The Giver by Louis Lowry, in a future where the ability to see any colour is genetically removed and drugs stop normal behaviour. Parents are selected and the society is run to a strict plan. Exactly how you described, but without time travel, although they do travel back in time through memories. Also, it's a novel. Hope this helps.

Comment: @beichst, it's definitely not "The Perfect Day", the protagonist wasn't a young boy

Comment: @Captain, it sounds like The Giver but it was definitely a short story, maybe it was a short story that became a novel. I will check it out

Comment: @DavePenn Ok, sorry I couldn't help more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it! It's called "[The New Utopia](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7015213-the-new-utopia)" by Jerome K. Jerome, it's available in PDF format [here](http://www.libertarian.co.uk/lapubs/cultn/cultn014.pdf).

> *'The
>   New Utopia' is a short story in which the author describes his dream
>   about a socialist society. Jerome's short essay describes a regimented
>   future city, indeed world, of nightmarish egalitarianism, where men
>   and women are barely distinguishable in their grey uniforms and all
>   have short black hair, natural or dyed.*